# List to String conversion

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of lists like so:

```
list = [[10, 11, 12, 13][14, 15, 16, 17]]
```

I want to convert them to Strings but maintain the list organization

```
list = [["10", "11", "12", "13"]["14", "15", "16", "17"]]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Note, a. `list` is a function. Try not redefining that as a variable. b. You need to put a comma to separate two lists. c. You can always use a map twice like -`map(lambda m: map(str, m), a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using nested [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) built-in function to perform the actual conversion:

```
lst = [[10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17]]
lst = [[str(x) for x in slst] for slst in lst]
```

Now `lst` will look as expected:

```
lst
=> [['10', '11', '12', '13'], ['14', '15', '16', '17']]
```

Also notice that it's a bad idea to name a variable `list`, that clashes with a built-in function name. That's why I renamed it to `lst`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]]
list=[map(str, list)for list in list]
print list
```

**RESULT: [['10', '11', '12', '13'], ['14', '15', '16', '17']]**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that you forgot to place a comma between your two sublist.

Secondly, do not use `list` as a variable name because you are shadowing the `list` data structure.

Finally, you can solve it using the `map` function:

```
>>> lst = [[10, 11, 12, 13],[14, 15, 16, 17]]
>>> map(lambda x: map(str, x), lst)
[['10', '11', '12', '13'], ['14', '15', '16', '17']]
>>>
```